# React multiple checkbox unchecking checkbox on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, function, checkbox

I am using checkboxes to filter array in react
This is my code.

```
 const [selectedSubCats, setSelectedSubCats] = useState([]);
  const [subCategoryName,setSubCategoryName] = useState([])

{subCategories?.map((item, index) => (
              <div className="category-checkbox" key={index}>
                <CheckBoxButton
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.name}
                  value={item.id}
                  onChange={(e)=>{
                    if (e.target.checked) {
                      setSelectedSubCats([...selectedSubCats, e.target.value]);
                      setSubCategoryName([...subCategoryName,e.target.name])
                    } else {
                      const newArr = selectedSubCats.filter((item) => item !== e.target.value);
                      setSelectedSubCats(newArr);
                     const namesArr = subCategoryName.filter((item) => item !== e.target.name)
                     setSubCategoryName(namesArr)
                    }

                  }}
                  text={item.name}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
```

I am also printing selected subcategories as an array

```
 {subCategoryName && (subCategoryName.map((name,index)=>(
                 <div key={index}>
                  <button style={{border:'none',padding:'10px 15px'}} type='submit'>{name}<AiOutlineClose/></button>
                 </div>
                 )))}
```

Is there a way to uncheck a selected checkbox from these buttons by passing id? or calling functions. I do not want all checkboxes to be unchecked, only from the selected buttons

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your names are unique, by name search the index in subCategories, change the subCategories itself, that should uncheck it.

To avoid unnecessary rerender, you have to do some extra work.